# How to check for the correct datetime format in TSQL function?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format

The function below expects following string

```
22.03.2016
28.02.2017 00:00:00
NULL
```

Sometimes the column contains garbage like `'22.003.2016'`.

How to manage this situation in T-SQL with SQL Server 2008 R2?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetItemDocDetailDataInput] 
    (@ItemDocDetailID uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS datetime2(7) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str nvarchar(20);
    DECLARE @dataInput datetime2(7);

    SELECT @str = ISNULL([DataInput], null) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             ISNULL([Value], '') AS [Value],    
             CASE
                WHEN [Value] IS NULL THEN NULL
                ELSE SUBSTRING([Value], 0, 11)
             END AS DataInput 
         FROM 
             ItemDocDetailParams 
         WHERE 
             ItemDocDetailID = @ItemDocDetailID 
             AND ItemParamTypeID = 12) D

    SELECT @dataInput = CONVERT(datetime2(7), @str, 103) 

    RETURN @dataInput;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the best approach is create another tsql function where I could check for dot positions in strings like

```
22.03.2016
28.02.2017 00:00:00
```

So I will use combination of following statements

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('.', '13.05.2019') AS FirstDot; 
3 -- ОК

SELECT CHARINDEX('.', '13.05.2019', 4) AS SecondDot;
6 -- ОК

SELECT CHARINDEX('.', '13.005.2019', 4) AS MatchPosition; 
7 --- NOT OK
```

Comment: I would assume the best approach is to fix the data model to store temporal data in properly typed date/time types instead of strings.

Comment: @DanGuzman I know it bro but there is no chance to do it. Anyway in later versions of MS SQL Server  there is try_parase() and try_convert() TSQL methods...